# "behave toward someone well" or "treat someone well"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please which sentence sounds the most natural.

> The teacher always behaves toward his students well.
>
> The teacher always treats his students well.

What I am trying to say is that the teacher is always kind to his students. If either of the sentences don't sound good, then could you offer the native sounding to express that?

Comment: Hmm. Not sure if it's inherently "ungrammatical", but your first example doesn't sit at all well with me. I don't think you can introduce a preposition-based adverbial clause *(**toward his students**)* in between a verb *(**behaves**)* and an associated simple adverb *(**well**)*. So it should be *He always **behaves well** towards his students*

Comment: I would add that "well" isn't a great word as it's not very descriptive. It begs the question: "Well" in what way?. Is he kind to them, generous to them, supportive of them?

Comment: Would "kindly" sound better then "well"?

Comment: As a native BrE speaker I would say that "_The teacher always treats his students well._" sounds the more natural. Although I agree with _Bee_ that "_well_"is a bit vague.

Comment: They both sound fine. Which sounds *better* is entirely a matter of opinion.